# Why $group is very slow in aggregation and how can faster it in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4, mongodb-3.2, mongodb-3.6

My query is taking ~3 seconds to execute with the $group stage, How can I faster this?

```
My query is:
db.getCollection('employee_data').aggregate([
  { $match: //Filter
  },
  { 
   $group: 
   {
     _id: {
       employee_id:"$employee_id",
       activity_date:"$activity_date"
     }, 
     trips: { $sum: 1 }
   }
  }
])
Data size : 4M records
```

Comment: Welcome to dba.se!  Right now, this question doesn't contain enough information for us to help you.  Please take a look at this quick article about [writing a good question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and if possible, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)

Answer (score 0):

As per MongoDB Documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) Groups documents by some specified expression and outputs to the next stage a document for each distinct grouping. The output documents contain an _id field which contains the distinct group by key. The output documents can also contain computed fields that hold the values of some accumulator expression grouped by the [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)’s _id field. [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) does not order its output documents.

The **`$group`** stage has the following prototype form:

```
{ $group: { _id: <expression>, <field1>: { <accumulator1> : <expression1> }, ... } }
```

The `_id` field is mandatory; however, you can specify an `_id` value of null, or any other constant value, to calculate accumulated values for all the input documents as a whole.

**$group Operator and Memory**

The [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage has a limit of **`100`** `megabytes of RAM`. By default, if the stage exceeds this limit, [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) will produce an error. However, to allow for the handling of large datasets, set the [allowDiskUse](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) option to true to enable [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operations to write to temporary files.

As per blog of `@VladMihalcea` [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/mongodb-facts-lightning-speed-aggregation/) the  [MongoDB aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) is extremely useful and its performances can’t go unnoticed.that didn’t require any extra optimization, aiming to demonstrate the out-of-the-box performance of MongoDB.

For further your ref [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)